# Determine precision at runtime in c

Tags: c, floating-point-precision

Is there anyway to determine percision at runtime using C commands?
there is `printf` command with dot notation:

```
printf("%.xf", number);
```

but x should be fixed before compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, specify an asterisk and provide the precision as a (int) parameter

```
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) printf("%.*f\n", k, 42.0);
```

Comment: Why there is only specifier for two arguments in `printf` ?

Comment: @haccks: the `*` in the conversion specifier consumes the first argument (`k`).

Comment: Note: When using `k=0; printf("%.*f\n", k, 42.0)`, "42" (no decimal point) is printed rather than "42.".  Use `k=0; printf("%#.*f\n", k, 42.0)`, to print the decimal point as in "42.".